# Is it possible for a client connected to a network to change its subnet to avoid IP filtering through a router?

Tags: networking

Internet protocol isn't really my forte, but I've recently been told to set up a network at my new workplace. I've hooked up four routers and made them connect to the same network.

I have two three main subnets in my network:

1. 172.16.0.xxx    (used for unrestricted network access for servers in the server room)
2. 172.16.208.xxx  (used for all other clients and forces all traffic to go through a proxy server)
3. 172.16.218.xxx  (used by guests and will redirect to a web log in page to prompt the user to log in)

The network works fine, I haven't found any way that the traffic can bypass the proxy server in the 172.16.208.xxx subnet, plus, I've made sure that no two clients can communicate with each other in the 208.xxx and 218.xxx subnet. However, is it possible for a client to manually change their settings on their PC, so that they are assigned an IP from 172.16.0.xxx and be able to browse the internet with no restriction? If so, how can it be done?

EDIT: 
To those who want to know how the network is configured,

*Each of the four routers is placed in each meeting room, and have one long LAN wire running out from each of them, connecting to a central 8-port ethernet hub. Each router is configured to broadcast 2 SSIDs: "Office_Main" "Office_Guest" and each SSID is configured to distribute "208.xxx" IPs and "218.xxx" IPs respectively (all the routers were also linked using a fancy wifi feature). All clients are isolated in the wifi access points, access to the internet is prohibited except for the proxy server. The servers are directly connected to the LAN, which has unrestricted access over the net.*

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a basic networking question, not a security one. Note that you should submit a basic drawing of your network before ppl can figure out your design.

Comment: The answer is simple ... it depends. How are the three subnets separated?

Comment: Each of the four routers is placed in each meeting room, and have one long LAN wire running out from each of them, connecting to a central 8-port ethernet hub. Each router is configured to broadcast 2 SSIDs: "Office_Main" "Office_Guest" and each SSID is configured to distribute "208.xxx" IPs and "218.xxx" IPs respectively (all the routers were also linked using a fancy wifi feature). All clients are isolated in the wifi access points, access to the internet is prohibited except for the proxy server. The servers are directly connected to the LAN, which has unrestricted access over the net.

Comment: There are a lot of factors as many have already suggested. The way you are suggesting is very messy to say the least and given the amount of patchwork here, chances are someone versed well in networking/security and a hacker can violate you in a minute. But with respect to average users or employees, not sure how much they know about your internals but relatively savvy people should be able to punch a hole. You really need to look into VLAN, at least RIP, static route important stuff, put your switches in server mode to name a few things. But again without a clear picture, hard to say for sure

Comment: Im not posting this as an answer because I dont know a definite answer to your question, but you may consider running nmap on your network from the 208 and 218 subnets, see what all is visible from each subnet to an aggressive network scanner. If i were a 1337 haxxor trying to get somewhere i shouldn't be, that is the first thing i would do in my attempts to get illegitimate access to your network. This will allow you to see any routes that need closed.

Comment: After doing an nmap scan, I can confirm that I see no other clients except for 172.16.208.1 (default gateway), 172.16.208.38 (local pc), 172.16.0.3 (print server), 172.16.0.2 (web server), 172.16.0.30/172.16.0.31 (DNS) and 172.16.0.32 (proxy server). The others in the office aren't too tech savvy, but changing the IP address on the pc seems trivial to do. I've experimented with changing client configurations myself, but they don't seem to be working (which is good news). I'm not convinced myself, though. I'll look into VLAN and RIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're on the right track, with a separate router for each partition.  This will keep users from being able to hop into the unrestricted network, as if they change their IP number, they won't be served any traffic, unless they also become part of the 172.16.0.* broadcast domain.

As folks have said, though, a crafty user may circumvent these partitions, allowing her to surf unrestricted.  Software may be installed on the 172.16.0.* network that accidentally opens it up, or, it may have to be opened up on purpose in a limited way to meet business demands...   So, I advise that you set up traffic monitoring facilities, like bandwidth/interface usage graphs (a myriad exist; MRTG is an oldie but a goodie), and know how to use your equipment's logging and packet-capturing facilities to examine traffic characteristics, and have an idea of what an average flow of traffic looks like, so as to compare it to a possibly abnormal flow of traffic.

As well, do employees know they're not to use the unrestricted Internet at work?  Is there an HR policy that prohibits network 'exploring'?  Are your bosses on board with these restrictions?  How do you intend to handle someone you might discover using the network in an unauthorized manner?

Issues of network security such as this aren't so much matters of 'if' as they are matters of 'when', and having prepared some for a breech, intentional or accidental, makes the event much less harrowing.